# How to properly format requests API json response with python?

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am working on a discord bot that gets information from an API. For this command I want to return some information, and display it nicely for the user. This is the code (Python 3.8.3, discord.py):

```py
import json
import requests
import discord

@bot.command(name="clan")
async def clan_command(ctx, clan_id:int):

    response = requests.get(f'https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/clans/info/?application_id=0a833f3e275be2c9b458c61d6cedf644&clan_id={clan_id}&fields=leader_name%2C+members_count%2C+tag%2C+motto%2C+name%2C+emblems.x256%2C+color', params={'q': 'requests+language:python'})
    json_response = response.json()
    repository = json_response["data"]

    clan_name = 
    clan_colour = 
    clan_url = f"https://eu.wargaming.net/clans/wot/{clan_id}/"
    clan_logo = 
    clan_commander = 
    clan_member_count = 
    clan_tag = 
    clan_motto = 

    embed = discord.Embed(title=clan_name (clan_tag), colour=clan_colour, url=clan_url)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=clan_logo)
    embed.add_field(name="Commander:", value=clan_commander, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Member count:", value=clan_member_count, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Clan motto:", value=clan_motto, inline=True)

    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Screenshot of the API response with input if I write it to a file `*clan 500075680`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQlvA.jpg

When I run this code:

```py
for key, value in repository.items():
    print(f"key {key} has value {value}")
```

I get this in console:

```
key 500075680 has value {'members_count': 81, 'name': 'Reloading', 'color': '#B80909', 'leader_name': 'Joc666', 'emblems': {'x256': {'wowp': 'https://eu.wargaming.net/clans/media/clans/emblems/cl_680/500075680/emblem_256x256.png'}}, 'tag': '-RLD-', 'motto': "In the end, we only regret the chances we didn't take."}
```

So the key *clan_id (which is a input argument that changes)* has multiple values.

My question is, if I take the clan_id = 500075680 for example, how do I display from value 'name': 'Reloading', Reloading individually?
How can I define the variables in my code?

**Fixed it thanks to you guys:**

I had the clan_id argument specified as an integer, removing that makes it work:
`clan_name = repository[clan_id]['name']`

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are looking for but it sounds like you want to access a nested JSON key which can be done like this -> `repository['500075680']['name']`

Comment: that number is a variable, if I do `clan_name = repository[clan_id]['name']` and then try to print clan_name, it gives me `Command raised an exception: KeyError: 500075680`

Comment: Look at the answers. You can loop through the top level keys instead of specifying them. If you only want 1 key with a specific value, use a try except block to loop through and print only the ones you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming value is dictionary
to acess the value of name from value dictionary use value['name']

```
for key, value in repository.items():
    print(f"key {key} has value {value['name']}")
```

from the image you shared, you  can get the value of name by using this `repository['data'][key]['name']`

if there are list of responses
example:
`repository=[{key1:{'name':name1}},{key2:{'name':name2}}`

```py
for item in repository:
    key=next(iter(item))
    print(item[key]['name'])
```

repository is a list holding all responses

Comment: `clan_name = repository['data'][clan_id]['name']` or `clan_name = repository['data'][key]['name']` (and then printing that) gives me `Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'data'` again.

Comment: repository['key']['name'] use this this should give the result make sure key is string

Comment: `Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'key'` again

Comment: {'500075680': {'members_count': 81, 'name': 'Reloading', 'color': '#B80909', 'leader_name': 'Joc666', 'emblems': {'x256': {'wowp': 'https://eu.wargaming.net/clans/media/clans/emblems/cl_680/500075680/emblem_256x256.png'}}, 'tag': '-RLD-', 'motto': "In the end, we only regret the chances we didn't take."}}

Comment: `print(repository['500075680']['name'])` check this

Comment: Yeah, this returns `Reloading`. But how can I make it a variable? Because `print(repository[clan_id]['name'])` does not work.

Comment: Sorry, I now know why. Because the input is an integer. It has to be a string...

Answer (score 1):

Try using [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

For example to get the value of `name` you could parse your json into a python dict and retrieve it from there.

```
for key, value in repository.items():
    value_dict = json.loads(value)
    print(value_dict["name"])
```

Comment: I am not actually writing the api response in a json file, that was just to explain what a response could be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another nice way to do it.

```
json_object = json.loads(json_response)
formatted_data = json.dumps(json_object, indent=2)
print(formatted_data)
```

**json.dumps** method with **indent** will formate it and you can controle the formatting with **indent** value.

It is equivalent to PHP array formatting after converting JSON to an array.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r()
```